# Как отобразить кнопку рядом с textarea?

Tags: html, css

Я пытаюсь нарисовать что-то такое:
[image]

проблема в том, что текущий вариант пришлось сделать с помощью таблицы: одна строка, два столбца, в одном textarea, в другом -- кнопка. Код положил здесь: http://pastebin.com/bsAhutPF

Вопрос: правильно ли так делать? можно ли сделать лучше?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Позиционировать элементы можно и без таблиц. Нужно использовать внешний div и два вложенных: textarea и a. Для textarea нужно указать свойство float:left, тогда кнопка (тег a) будет обтекать это поле. Только тег a должен быть встроенным (нельзя писать display:block).
Мой набросок [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/57Keh/5/).

Answer (score 1):

```
<textarea style="width: 300px; height: 100px;"></textarea>
<a href="#" style="width: 80px; padding: 5px; background: #000; position: absolute; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; color: #FFF;">Parse it</a>
```